# Search inside a string with Whooshalchemy?

Tags: python, search, flask, whoosh

I'm building a text search with python and Flask-Whooshalchemy, currently I have something like this:

```
Entry.query.whoosh_search('something').all()
```

Which goes through body and title of Entry. However, it returns true only if content has that exact string. So for example

```
Entry.query.whoosh_search('cat').all()
```

returns entries with "I have a cat" but not "housecat" or "cats".

How can I make the search find strings inside strings?

Comment: Based on the reply [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/whoosh/ZvKHCXIB10k) you might want to try `Entry.query.whoosh_search('*cat*').all()` (added *).  According the linked reply that should call the `whoosh.query.Wildcard` class in the default `whoosh.qparser.QueryParser` in Whoosh, which I believe WhooshAlchemy makes use of by default.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Entry.query.whoosh_search('*something*').all()
```

'*' is for zero or more characters.